# App in google play not showing on newest samsung galaxy's

Tags: android, google-play, samsung-galaxy

I was looking at newest phones at the store today and found out that my app cant be seen in google play on S10, S10+, S10e, S9, S9+ and NOTE9. Other Motorola, Huawei, Honor... works fine. And its strange because on my emulator Pixel2 with Android Pie and with google play store it works fine too. In google play console/release management/device catalog it says that all newer galaxy phones are supported but in reality they are not. Target API in my app is 27 but that shouldn't matter, wright!? 
Anyways, how do I fix that?

Comment: You should talk to Google. Not really a question for this site (too broad, off topic).

Comment: Well, I did talk to google support, first they told me that it should be supported, then they gave me tips (clean cache and data of google play and services app) which didn't work, and finally they basically told me that they cant teach me to code!?